# Handle null value from database

Tags: java

I use this code to get Merchant name by ID.

```
@GetMapping("pages")
public Page<WpfPaymentsDTO> pages(@RequestParam(value = "page") int page, @RequestParam(value = "size") int size) {
    return wpfPaymentsService.findAll(page, size)
                             .map(g -> WpfPaymentsDTO.builder()
                             .id(g.getId())
                             .status(g.getStatus())
                             .merchant_id(getMerchantName(g.getMerchant_id()))
                             .build());  
}

private String getMerchantName(Integer id) {      
    return Optional.ofNullable(id)
                   .flatMap(i -> merchantService.findById(i))
                   .map(Merchants::getName)
                   .orElse("");
}
```

But when name is not found I get `java.lang.NullPointerException: null at this line: .merchant_id(getMerchantName(g.getMerchant_id()))` because value `g.getMerchant_id()` is `null` into DB.

Is there some solution for this?

**Stacktrace (first lines)**

```
14:48:55.849 [default task-1] ERROR o.s.b.w.s.support.ErrorPageFilter - Forwarding to error page from request [/wpf_payments/pages] due to exception[null]
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at deployment.datalis_admin.war//org.datalis.admin.backend.restapi.WpfPaymentsController.lambda$pages$1(WpfPaymentsController.java:169)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:927)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at deployment.datalis_admin.war//org.springframework.data.domain.Chunk.getConvertedContent(Chunk.java:167)
    at deployment.datalis_admin.war//org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl.map(PageImpl.java:106)
    at deployment.datalis_admin.war//org.datalis.admin.backend.restapi.WpfPaymentsController.pages(WpfPaymentsController.java:164)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
```

Comment: while processing check g.getMerchant_id()!=null

Comment: Simply remove the merchants with null IDs from the database. I think this should have been the primary key field, unless you have some PK like a UUID, and `id` is a natural primary key.

Comment: I can't remove them. And they are not primary keys - just a reference number defined as int.

Answer (score 4):

If the NullPointerException appears at that line, I doubt it has to do with the merchand_id. Could you make sure that .status(g.getStatus()) doesn't return null?

Java would report NullPointerException at the line you mentioned only if "g" were null. But it cannot be since it is used before.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably several solutions for this. Based on the code you provided the easiest would be to filter out all merchants were `g.getMerchant_id()` is `null`:

```
wpfPaymentsService.findAll(page, size)
                  .filter(g -> g.getMerchant_id() != null)
                  .map(g -> WpfPaymentsDTO.builder()
                                          .id(g.getId())
                                          .status(g.getStatus())
                                          .merchant_id(getMerchantName(g.getMerchant_id()))
                                          .build()
                  );
```

This should fix the `NullPointerException`, but it might not be want you want. That depends on your requirements. Are Merchants without an ID allowed in the result etc.

Comment: but I have to change the return method to Streamable<Object>?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. My initial code had an error. Check again. This should be the right solution now.

Comment: How I can check 2 values? Like this? `.filter(g -> g.getMerchant_id() != null,  g.getContract_id() != null)`?

Comment: @PeterPenzov `.filter(g -> g.getMerchant_id() != null && g.getContract_id() != null)` :)

Comment: @PeterPenzov You can use as many `filter()` statements as you want. `Stream.filter().filter().filter()` etc. But beware: They are all "and" relations. The objects in the stream have to fulfil all the `filter()` criteria.

Comment: is there some way to filter them "independently"? I mean just to skip the missing values?

Comment: @PeterPenzov Not sure what you mean with that.

Comment: Can you show me how to implement properly Stream.filter().filter().filter()?

Comment: @PeterPenzov Look at the other answer. I think he is right. Please add the first 10 lines of the stacktrace to your question so that we can better understand where the NPE is actually coming from.

Comment: Very strange.  Added `.filter(g -> g.getMerchant_id() != null)` but nothing is returned. Looks like the entire object is not returned when there is some null value.

Comment: Can you propose some other solution, please?

Comment: @PeterPenzov It is not yet clear what the problem is. So it is hard to help you with a solution. You have to provide more detail and dig deeper to find out what is actually causing the `NullPointerException`. See @Mihai answers.

Comment: I see that into DB Merchant_id is NULL. So it's normal to get NPE for it. The question is how to continue code execution then the value is NULL?

Comment: @PeterPenzov Not necessarily. There is a lot of "software" in between that might change that behaviour. You assume that this is the cause for the NPE, but you do not know. In that case you usually debug your application with a debugger until you get to the point in your code where things go wrong. IDEs like IntelliJ allow you to specifically set breakpoints to exceptions like NPEs.